# Destructring list of lists generates lists pointing to the same memory

Tags: python

While answering another question I found the following behaviour:

```
N=4

a,b = [[0]*N]*2
# [[0]*N]*2: [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
# a: [0,0,0,0]
# b: [0,0,0,0]
for i in range(N):
    a[i]= 1
    b[i] = 2
# a: [2,2,2,2]
# b: [2,2,2,2]
```

Leaving aside that this code is not very Pythonic. Can someone explain why a and b are overwriting each other? I would expect that the destructing brakes the original list into two independent lists however `(id(a)==id(b))==True`. Is there only truly one list in memory? Why?

Comment: Because `a` & `b` are the same list that you created with `[[0]*N]*2`

Comment: @rdas "Because a & b are the same list" - they aren't !?!?

Comment: The answer linked was suggested by another commenter explains why the are the same list, thanks!.